# Improve code that factorizes in a faster way?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, optimization, factorization

I would like to make this piece of code faster. It returns all the factors (prime numbers) of a long number. It obviously takes minutes to be executed if the `longNumber` is a particular one.

```
int div = 2;
String factors = "";

while (longNumer != 1)
{
    if (longNumer % div == 0)
    {
        longNumer /= div;
        factors += div + " ";
    }
    else { div++; }
}

//longNumber = 10, gives: 2 5. 
//longNumber = 150, gives: 3 5 7.
//longNumber = 10523, gives: 17 619.
```

It takes too long with numbers such "7544222046562688368", and it's not good, what would you suggest?

Comment: Use memoization for the prime numbers and the code will have a boost of performance.

Comment: If your algorithm really does give `3,5,7` as the factors of `150` I suggest you make it right before you waste time making it faster.

Answer (score 4):

For large numbers you can use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to first find the prime numbers up to sqrt(n) and then you have to check that whether those prime numbers are factors

Comment: This won't help much for 64 bit numbers, there are still a lot of primes below `2^32` to check against, and generating them will add diminishing returns anyway.

Comment: Using the Sieve of Eratosthenes to get the first sqrt(n) primes takes about sqrt(n) loglog n operations. Trial division takes sqrt(n) operations. What are you gaining by sieving?

Comment: @DouglasZare Yes, a sieve takes more operations than trial division.  But the operations in question are very different.  Division is about 10 times slower for a CPU than addition, and `log(log(n))` is effectively constant over the range of values that you can fit in a long.  (And said constant is significantly smaller than 10.)

Your choice of language may add enough overhead to mask this performance difference.  But in an efficient language, a well-implemented sieve is likely to beat trial division over anything that can be put in a long.

Comment: @btilly: I don't think a nearly optimized sieve is a fair comparison, since optimizing a sieve is a lot harder than the question asked in this problem. For the same restricted range, you get much of the benefit of a sieve by simply avoiding trial division by composites divisible by small primes (an ingredient in making a sieve efficient, hence simpler). Further, you gain by stopping early, without narrowing down the set of primes past what you need. The sieve implementations I have seen are not designed to do that although they could be modified.

Comment: @DouglasZare When I was working with Project Euler problems some years ago, I did a sieve implementation that came back as a stream in Perl, and beat trial division in the same language by a noticeable amount.  And the code wasn't too hard to write.

Comment: @btilly: Good for you. Did you test equally optimized versions, or a decent sieve against no optimizations for trial division? I just implemented the naive sieve of Eratosthenes on the Wikipedia page linked in C#. It took 3 seconds on one 2 GHz processor to list the primes up to 10^8. Trying 10^9 generated on out of memory exception. This does not include the time for using the list of primes. Naive trial division on the same system, with no optimization like avoiding testing even composites, took 1.4 seconds up to 10^8, and 14 seconds up to 10^9, of course without using much memory.

Comment: Trial division is easy to stop early, which helps a lot in this problem, but it is not easy to stop early with a sieve. See the "incremental sieve" section of the Wikipedia page, which includes the statements, "Incremental versions of the sieve are always slower and take more memory than the non-incremental versions...a large constant factor slower to process than the usual implementation using an array..." A sieve is reasonable if you are generating a list of primes to use over and over. It is not easy to beat trial division using a sieve if you are trying to factor one number.

Comment: @DouglasZare From memory, my implementations special cased things to 1 and 5 mod 6.  For the sieve the only additional significant optimization was using a bit vector  This made a surprisingly big impact on performance.  And under the hood when I needed to sieve more for a prime I'd simply sieve another block of a 100k or so numbers.  I'm sure the logic added some overhead to my sieve, but it wasn't a large constant factor.

Comment: Of course all of this is performance stuff.  Which means it very much is YMMV territory.  Changing languages, implementations, operating systems, computers and so on may result in very different experiences.  And for non-obvious reasons.  For example I said that adding logic added overhead to my sieve.  But maybe it was the other way around, maybe processing the same block of memory over and over again kept it in CPU cache which helped my performance!  But the moral remains.  You never know which is faster until you do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following steps instead -

**1.** Find all prime numbers <= sqrt(longNumber). And save them in a array - `primes`.
**2.** Now gradually use the element of the array - `primes` as a divisor to find the factor.

Comment: isn't looping through an array is pretty bad in terms of performance?

Comment: @HashMap it's not. It depends if the array has 10 or 1m elements what determines the good/bad performance.

Comment: I would say that you should seek the prime numbers if and only if they're not stored in the array. You can do a quick look up by using binary search (assuming you store the prime numbers in a sorted way in the array).

Comment: `sqrt(longNumber)` will still be a long number. This won't help much for 64 bit numbers, there are still a lot of primes below `2^32` to check against, and generating them will add diminishing returns anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The answers suggesting the Sieve of Eratosthenes will not do much for numbers like you describe. For `64` bit numbers `sqrt(2^64) = 2^32`, which is still a lot.

For those, your best bets are [Pollard's Rho algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) or the more complex integer factorization methods listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization):

> Algebraic-group factorisation algorithms, among which are Pollard's p − 1 algorithm, Williams' p + 1 algorithm, and Lenstra elliptic curve factorization
>
> Fermat's factorization method
>
> Euler's factorization method
>
> Special number field sieve

Answer (score 2):

Before you implement one of the factoring algorithms faster than trial division, one easily corrected mistake is to avoid doing the trial division past the sqrt of the last piece.

```
while (longNumber != 1) {
    if (longNumber % div == 0) {
        longNumber /= div;
        factors += div + " ";
    }
    else {
        if (div*div>longNumber) {
            if (longNumber > 1)
                factors += longNumber + " ";
            break; // leave the while loop.  
        } 
        div++; 
    }
}
```

Let the two largest prime factors be P1 and P2. In your version, you do about c P1 operations. In the modified version, you do about c Max(sqrt(P1),P2). On 7544222046562688368, the improvement should be a factor of 45.

Another improvement is to change the div++ line. You don't need to do trial division by even numbers greater than 2, or by numbers divisible by 3 greater than 3. Avoiding these speeds up the calculation by more than another factor of 2, and you can do slightly better by avoiding testing multiples of other small primes. However, you don't want to take time to do trial divisions of div by small primes. Instead, you keep track of the current and allowable remainders mod 2*3*5*7, say. This is called using a wheel for the small primes.

Some other answers have talked about using a sieve to find all small primes, and then using trial division only by these. This doesn't help if you are factoring just one number since it takes too long to sieve out the primes. Producing a list of the primes up to sqrt(n) takes about c sqrt(n) loglog n operations, while trial division by everything up to sqrt(n) takes about c sqrt(n) operations. Performing a sieve once and storing the results can help if you need to factor many large numbers.

Comment: I don't think there's any way for `div*div > longNumber` to be true since in that case you've already found all the prime factors and `longNumber` has been reduced to 1.

Comment: @Anonymous: div*div can be greater than longNumber when you just have one prime factor left. Suppose longNumber starts at 7. You test div=2, then div=3 and 3*3>7, and then you know 7 is prime so you don't need to test any higher values of div. If longNumber starts at 14, you find the factor of 2, reducing it to 7, test 2 again, then at 3 you can stop.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to factor 64-bit integers, that's both simple to program and reasonably efficient in practice, combines trial division and Pollard's rho algorithm. Here's pseudocode:

```
function factors(n)
    wheel := [1,2,2,4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6]
    w, f, fs := 0, 2, []
    while f*f <= n and f < 10000
        while n % f == 0
            fs, n := f :: fs, n / f
        f, w := f + wheel[w], w+1
        if w = 11 then w = 3
    if n == 1 return fs
    h, t, g, c := 1, 1, 1, 1
    while not isPrime(n)
        repeat
            h := (h*h+c) % n # the hare runs
            h := (h*h+c) % n # twice as fast
            t := (t*t+c) % n # as the tortoise
            g := gcd(t-h, n)
        while g == 1
        if isPrime(g)
            while n % g == 0
                fs, n := g :: fs, n / g
        h, t, g, c := 1, 1, 1, c+1
    return n :: fs
```

This uses a 2,3,5-wheel for trial division up to 10000 followed by a simple implementation of the rho algorithm; it should factor your sample number as 7544222046562688368 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 7 * 7 * 14618561 * 658254407 in a few milliseconds. Improvements are possible, but that should be enough to get you started.